# libnl-3 includes broken?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ipc, netlink

I am trying to use libnl 3 (http://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/) under Ubuntu to use netlink in order to get some information from the IPv6 Neighbour Cache.

I am including a bunch of headers for this lib, but gcc already fails for the first one:

```
#include <libnl3/netlink/netlink.h>
```

There is no "main header", like libnl.h.

```
>$ gcc netlink_test.c 
In file included from netlink_test.c:11:0:
/usr/include/libnl3/netlink/netlink.h:24:36: fatal error: netlink/netlink-compat.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

The file netlink.h includes "netlink/netlink-compat.h". Unfortunately, there is no "/usr/include/netlink/" folder. There is only "/usr/include/libnl3/netlink/"

Including "netlink/netlink.h" thus gives me:

```
netlink_test.c:10:29: fatal error: netlink/netlink.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I have installed the following packages under Ubuntu 12.04:

```
libnl-3-200
libnl-3-200-dbg
libnl-3-dev
libnl-3-doc
libnl-genl-3-200
libnl-genl-3-200-dev
libnl-route-3-200
libnl-route-3-200-dev
```

Am I missing here something or is this genuinely broken?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, so the package is not broken, I am ;)

A short while ago, they introduced a mechanism to enable users to install different versions of this library.
Now you can configure it using "pkg-config" or just pass the precise directory to the compiler with "-I /usr/include/libnl3/".
And it works.

Comment: I have the same error except I am doing cross-compiling. I have to precisely direct the compiler with "-I<sysroot>/usr/include/libnl3".