# compiling keepalived from source not working

Tags: c, linux, makefile

i have been trying to compile and install keepalived like in the following link http://www.keepalived.org/doc/installing_keepalived.html

i'm building it on ubuntu/trusty64 vagrant machine
i have installed all the requirement specified in the document

```
sudo apt-get install curl gcc libssl-dev libnl-3-dev libnl-genl-3-dev libsnmp-dev
```

when i made 'make' command 
it showed me the following error

```
gcc -g -O2   -I/usr/src/linux/include -I/usr/src/linux/include -
DLIBIPVS_USE_NL -Wall -Wunused -c -o libipvs.o libipvs.c
In file included from libipvs.h:13:0,
             from libipvs.c:23:
ip_vs.h:15:29: fatal error: netlink/netlink.h: No such file or directory
#include <netlink/netlink.h> <-(the terminal saying that the error)
```

i tried that answer
[libnl-3 includes broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686752/libnl-3-includes-broken)
i entered

```
sudo make -I /usr/include/libnl3
```

or

```
make -I /usr/include/libnl3
```

but both failed i'm kind new c compiling and building in linux so i would aperciate any help

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617973/fatal-error-netlink-genl-genl-h-no-such-file-or-directory) help?

Comment: Might also try `sudo apt-get install libnl-route-3-dev`

Comment: Take a look around on your file system and see if you don't already have netlink.h somewhere. If it's in a netlink sub-directory, then add that path to your gcc command line (example: `-I/user/src/netlink`).

Comment: i tried both and it didn;t work sorry